# Using stringBuilder in combination with String.format

Tags: android, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I have an alert dialog that works fine, but I suspect I can clean up my code some.  I'm using a `stringBuilder` to help pull together the message, in addition to using String.format to get the spacing pleasant for each line.  It's the `String.format` that keeps me from appending like normal.  I'd rather not use four (4) String Objects to accomplish all this.  Show me a more concise coding and be cool forever.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Total Counts");

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String one= String.format("%-10s %s", calCount1, "#1 count\n");
        String two= String.format("%-10s %s", calCount2, "#2 count\n");
        String three= String.format("%-10s %s", calCount3, "#3 count\n");
        String four= String.format("%-10s %s", calCount4, "#4 count\n");

        stringBuilder.append(one);
        stringBuilder.append(two);
        stringBuilder.append(three);
        stringBuilder.append(four);

        builder.setMessage(stringBuilder.toString());
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("Total Counts");

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-10s %s", calCount1, "#1 count\n"));
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-10s %s", calCount2, "#2 count\n"));
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-10s %s", calCount3, "#3 count\n"));
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-10s %s", calCount4, "#4 count\n"));

    builder.setMessage(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are gaining anything by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatting placeholders in string resources. See [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), under the section "Formatting Strings". It should work with the standard formatting modifiers like you have.